# Why am I seeing notifications of activity on favorites?

Tags: bug, status-completed, favorites-notifications

Recently, I've started seeing notifications of changes to favorites in my recent activity page, even though I've checked the "*I don't want notifications of activity on questions I've favorited*" option.

Has something changed or is this no longer working? I've seen this happening on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow and Super User.

Comment: What do you mean by "notifications" specifically?  The "New Replies" envelop is lighting up?  A banner message appears?

Comment: @Jarrod I see the "New replies" envelope, yes. Right now, I also got a banner message saying: "You have 1 new comment; 1 favorite change". This seems to be happening on all the sites I'm active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some differences between the queries that lit the envelope and those that returned data on the /users/recent page - these have been refactored to use the same code.

And it will respect your favorite preference!