# Favorites new activity indicator

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, favorites-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detail Recent Favorite changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes)

I am seeing notifications of activity for the favorites tab, just like this question describes: [Why am I seeing notifications of activity on favorites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67078/why-am-i-seeing-notifications-of-activity-on-favorites) **However,** when I click on the tab, I don't see any indication as to which favorite actually has new activity.

I noticed a list of feature requests for the favorites tab, but this one is not in there and it seems pretty crucial.

Couldn't we highlight the updated questions somehow? Am I missing something?

Comment: I want to know what part of the thread has been updated/where new info has been posted. Preferably with a direct link to that section.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your favorites by [recent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627569/citizen-conn?tab=favorites#fpage_1-fsort_recent)
Then you'll view, when the last action was.

Comment: this helps, but it's not a substitute for a visual highlight...

Comment: ... and it doesn't help if the favorite notification was due to a comment on the question.